# Change image without the need of a button

Tags: javascript, html

Every where I look I find questions and sulotions on how to change a picture source, but there is button involved.

I just want to change the source of my picture depending on a tag value.

```
<script>
function changeBG(tag) {
    if (tag.value > 0)

        var image = document.getElementById('square');
        image.src = "images/green.bmp"

    iX.createTag('__ix_background_data_any_se_open', changeBG, 'interval')
}
</script>

<img src="images/info_trans.bmp" id="square" class="square" style="position:absolute;left:726px;top:22px;" />
```

So what I want with the code above is:

When `__ix_background_data_any_se_open` has value `0` gray.bmp will show.

If `__ix_background_data_any_se_open` has a value above `0` green.bmp will show.

Comment: How do you intend to trigger the code? You need somekind of trigger or else when does you code run? If it's on load use the onload trigger. `'interval'` seems to suggest you want to use `setInterval`

Comment: ^^ nothing will happen without a trigger. That's why most people suggest buttons and the (on)click event

Comment: *When __ix_background_data_any_se_open has value 0*; Right so it's onchange of `__ix_background_data_any_se_open`...whatever that is? To answer this question we need more information.

Comment: so onchange, check the value and apply conditions on it... he could totally do this himself ;D

Comment: the process of changing the source is identical however you cause it to happen. Examples probably use buttons to trigger the process because it's a convenient way to demo it. The two things are not inherently connected. If you know how to change the image source, then that's sorted. Now you need to find out how to detect when the value of your tag has changed.

Comment: When I try this: 
<script>
        function seOpen(tag) {
            if (tag.value > 0)
                alert('se');
            
        }
        iX.createTag('__ix_background_data_any_se_open', seOpen, 'interval')
        
    </script>

Things turns out ok. When __ix_background_data_any_se_open is larger than 0 I will get a pop up saying "se".

Isn't this the same trigger as my first code?